# Secure communication between two servers

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, hsm

I want to securely store private keys of my users on a separate server (lets call it **B**) and it's used to sign, decrypt information. **B** stores keys on a database (postgres).   Server  **A** (public)  sends *information* to **B**. Ideally **B** needs to get the private key, sign the token with *information* and send it back to **A**. Instead of sending the private key to **A**, which can be a security issue (if server **A** is compromised).

My options are:

1. web sockets
2. Https request (https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback)

Questions:

1. Is there any other options to securely communicate with two servers?
2. If server **B** was on port "7000" how can I make sure only server **A** can access it?
3. How does HSM server help in my case and how does it communicate with other servers (websocket or https request)?

I could just take the easy route and connect database of server **B** on port "7000" and run queries from **A** but as I said it's not as secure. I heard that HSM handles/decrypts information and sends it back, so I though I can do something similar with normal servers.

Thanks any help would be appreciated

---

**UPDATE**

@zaph has answered questions 2 and 3.

**Question:** Does server **A** need to do a *https* request and include the private *ip* address of server **B**, for example `https://203.0.113.25`? Then server **B** would use an *API router* to handle the request. However **ip** isn't a DNS, therefore it won't work due to certificates. So how do servers communicate, send/receive data?

Reference: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Scenario3.html

Comment: Q2. Do not connect Server B to the Internet, use a direct Ethernet connection between server B to a second Ethernet port on server A. That kind makes server B like an HSM without tamper resistance.

Comment: @zaph haha, thanks tamper-resstance is what I need :) And in case using HSM does server A need to be specially/differntly configured? and does it have special features apart from tamper-resitance? How would you store information in HSM, memorry or database?

Comment: downvoters comment below...

Comment: Nothing specific for server A, server B must be completely secure, or as secure as possible, access must be carefully controlled, 2-factor authentication at a minimum. But the real first step is to create a threat model, what is at risk and the value to all parties including the attacker. The capabilities of the attacker you are defending against in time, skill and resources: a curious teen to a well funder nation-state. You can not create 100% security so you need to define what is required.

Comment: @zaph thank you, yet I am still not sure about Q1. I don't think making a http request is appropriate and web sockets are really made for client to server connections. What do people usually use?

Comment: @zaph after reading http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Scenario3.html, as I understood I need to directly make an ip request (not DNS) from **A** to my private server **B**. Eg:  `https:/10.0.0.0/16` is that right or do I need to use another technique?

Comment: Again, I can't help with that.

Comment: Ok @zaph - Dan, thank you, up-voted :)

Comment: Have you considered an HSM instead of server B?

Comment: @EJP yes, I have. But I'd like to know how the two servers send/receive data to each other, as server **B** isn't going to be connected to the internet. I know that in AWS you need to create a new instance, and connect it to server **A**. Since HSM is similar to server **B**, it will be helpful to understand the concept and techniques.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For others:** Use security groups, configure them so only a specific instance can access it. Make a normal request, e.g.: `domain.com:PORT`. PORT is the instance that's listening to request...

> When you specify a security group as the source or destination for a
>   rule, the rule affects all instances associated with the security
>   group. Incoming traffic is allowed based on the private IP addresses
>   of the instances that are associated with the source security group
>   (and not the public IP or Elastic IP addresses).

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html